# SQL simplification possible?

Tags: sql, postgresql, relational-division

I'm asked the following question concerning the table below

> Display NPRO and LIBELLE from SAPIN products that are ordered only in
>   Toulouse

Here is my answer (it is correct) but I feel like it could be simplified somehow.

Is there a way to make it easier?

```
select npro, libelle
from produit
where libelle like '%SAPIN%'
and npro in 
(select npro from detail where ncom in
(select ncom from commande where ncli in
(select ncli from client where localite='Toulouse')))
and npro not in
(select npro from detail where ncom in
(select ncom from commande where ncli in
(select ncli from client where localite<>'Toulouse')))
```

[image]

Comment: Check if it eturns correct results: `SELECT p.npro, p.libelle
FROM produit p
JOIN detail d
  ON p.npro = d.npro
JOIN commande c
  ON d.ncom = c.ncom
JOIN client cl
  ON cl.ncli = c.ncli
WHERE p.libelle LIKE '%SAPIN%'
GROUP BY p.npro, p.libelle
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN cl.localite = 'Toulouse' THEN 1 END) > 0
   AND COUNT(CASE WHEN cl.localite <> 'Toulouse' THEN 1 END) = 0`

Comment: @lad2025 Yes, it returns the correct result. Thanks for the answer but is there maybe an easier way to do this? Or am I forced to do it like that?

Comment: Side note: I **really** hope this is test or otherwise anonymized data.  As opposed to actual customer records.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse Of course it is, this is for a DB class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to make it easier to read is to use:

```
SELECT p.npro, p.libelle
FROM produit p
JOIN detail d
  ON p.npro = d.npro
JOIN commande c
  ON d.ncom = c.ncom
JOIN client cl
  ON cl.ncli = c.ncli
WHERE p.libelle LIKE '%SAPIN%'
GROUP BY p.npro, p.libelle
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN cl.localite = 'Toulouse' THEN 1 END) > 0
   AND COUNT(CASE WHEN cl.localite <> 'Toulouse' THEN 1 END) = 0
```

How it works:

- join tables that you need
- filter from products `p.libelle` that contains `SAPIN`
- group by `p.npro` and `p.libelle`
- filter result of aggregation: first count `localite` equal `Touluse` and with second count other `localite`.

Answer (score 1):

EXISTS+ NOT EXISTS is the simplest. (IMHO)

```
SELECT npro, libelle
FROM produit p
WHERE p.libelle LIKE '%SAPIN%'
AND EXISTS (
        SELECT *  
        FROM detail d  
        JOIN commande co ON co.ncom = d.ncom
        JOIN client cl ON cl.ncli = co.ncli
        WHERE d.npro = p.npro
        AND cl.localite = 'Toulouse'
        )
AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM detail d
        JOIN commande co ON co.ncom = d.ncom
        JOIN client cl ON cl.ncli = co.ncli
        WHERE d.npro = p.npro
        AND cl.localite <> 'Toulouse'
        );
```

Comment: Yes this was also an option but a bit long if you want my opinion. But still, it adds an option so upvote.